# How to run the WCF Test Client whenever the service is running

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, wcf-client

I have a WCF project. When I run it sometimes launches the WCF Test Client and sometimes it does not.

How can I set the WCF Test Client to always open?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The link in MLF's answer does contain good information, and is definitely worth a read.  However, it took me a while to find the specific answer I was looking for, which is about halfway down the page:

> If you set the focus on the .svc or .xamlx file in Solution Explorer, WCF Test Client will start when pressing F5.

This still holds true in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: And Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: ...and, in a multi-project solution, ensure the service's is "Set as Startup Project" before hitting F5 ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Have look at this article from the WCF Tools Team Blog

[Tips for Launching WCF Test Client](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wcftoolsteamblog/archive/2010/01/04/tips-for-launching-wcf-test-client.aspx)

Comment: If you set the focus on the .svc or .xamlx file in Solution Explorer, WCF Test Client will start when pressing F5

Comment: In the meantime the hyperlink got broken. However the contents can be found at archive.org: https://web.archive.org/web/20160305201409/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wcftoolsteamblog/archive/2010/01/04/tips-for-launching-wcf-test-client.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noticing the comment, generated by the project template at one's svc.cs-file:

```
// NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select SampleService.svc or SampleService.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
public class SampleService : ISampleService
{
    ...
```

One can also use that hint, to make WCF Test Client start each and every time (regardless of the currently focused file) by specifiying the the svc-file as start action.

Go to your "project properties", "Web", and set "Specific Page" to your svc-file.