# WCFTestClient won't launch

Tags: wcftestclient

I am running VS2010 on Win7. For some reason WCFTestClient.exe won't execute. If I run this from Command line, it shows up in the task manager for split second and then dies. It won't run from VS as well. Has anybody run into this before?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set that the WCF Test Client will run every time the service is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805818/how-to-set-that-the-wcf-test-client-will-run-every-time-the-service-is-running)

Comment: Duplicate. Here's your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31223693/105539

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,and it is fixed now because i had a problem in the App.Config file,i renamed a service but didn't update the config file